# jquery handlers not working with dynamically added id

Tags: jquery, dynamic, click, knockout.js

I have the following element on my page, which gets a dynamically added ID from my javascript MVC framework:

```
<input data-bind="attr: { id: attributeName }" type="text" />
```

When the element gets dynamically rendered on the page, the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="job_title" data-bind="attr: { id: attributeName }" type="text" />
```

However, when I attempt to click function to the input box, it doesn't work.  (The same code works on a pre-existing input element though).

```
$("#job_title").click(function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

The above code doesn't seem to work when the input element is dynamically added to the page with a dynamic "id" attribute.  I'm adding this element to the page in a knockout.js foreach loop, but I don't know if that matters. Has anyone else run into this?

Here's the real code... how can I simulate the $("body").on() method to replace this:

```
 $("#job_title").typeahead({
    source: searchFunction,        
    onselect: function(obj) {            
    }
 });
```

Comment: because the dynamically added input element does not exist on the page when you assigned the click event.. so technically the click event never got bound.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but if i do this alert("#job_title").length).  It returns 1 and not 0.

Comment: @AdamLevitt I believe because it recognizes it, but the click event isn't bound to it.

Comment: where do you have that alert?

Comment: I push the element to the page, and on the following line I add the click handler.  Is it a race condition?

Comment: would want to see the code how you push the element to the page and where do you assign the click handler

Comment: Take a look at Andrew's answer below.  The $("body").on() worked, but I will update my original post now to force through my real code.  How can I convert the body.on to this:  $("#job_title").typeahead({
    source: searchFunction,        
    onselect: function(obj) {            
    }
 });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try:

`$("body").on("click", "#job_title", function() {  alert('hi');
});`

This should work, as `click` doesn't because you're dynamically adding the element.

Comment: So this works... which gets me to the first part of my solution.  Now, since I'm really using this as a primitive example to really use the twitter-bootstrap typeahead plugin.  How could I use this to simulate this code:  $("#job_title").typeahead({
        source: searchFunction,        
        onselect: function(obj) {            
        }
    });

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing a custom knockout binder like so

```
ko.bindingHandlers.typehead = {
    init: function(e){
        $(e).typeahead({
            source: searchFunction,        
            onselect: function(obj) {            
            }
         });
    }
};
```

Then apply the binder like any other Knockout binder

```
<input id="job_title" data-bind="attr: { id: attributeName }, typehead:true" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a click data-bind? Something like:

```
<input data-bind="attr: { id: attributeName }, click: functionToCall" type="text" />
```

This would allow you abstract away from DOM manipulation, which is one of the main advantages of using databinding in the first place. You can even have that function come from a property on your view model which can react dynamically to the context.

Comment: The thing is I need to add the twitter-bootstrap typeahead plugin onto the element...

Comment: In that case a custom binding may actually be the way to go - something like Wiz's answer